# Access values from assertion expression in assertion message

Tags: python, python-3.x, assert, assertion

I have an assert statement `assert x == y, f"Ensure x {x} is equal to y {y}."`, where both x and y are non-trivial and relatively long expressions. Can I access the result of these expressions in the assertion message, such that I don't have to write them out again?

I was thinking of something like `assert x == y, f"Ensure x {%0} is equal to y {%1}."`, where %0 is bound to the first, and %1 to the second expression of the comparison.

I know I can do

```
x = ...
y = ...
assert x == y, f"Ensure x {x} is equal to y {y}."
```

But I am looking for a one-line solution.

Comment: You're aware of the `:=` walrus operator…?

Comment: You mean like `assert (x := ab) == (y := cd), f"Ensure x {x} is equal to y {y}."`?

Comment: That’s what I had in mind.

Comment: Yeah, that seems reasonable! Thanks. Probably as good as it's going to get. Although it introduces some syntax overhead and just yesterday I had to use a 3.6 interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a function?

```
def assert_x_eq_y(x, y):
    assert x == y, f"Ensure x {x} is equal to y {y}."
```

Then the code where it's used becomes one line:

```
assert_x_eq_y(x, y)
```

For example:

```
a = 'foo'
b = 'foobar'

assert_x_eq_y(a*2, b[:len(b)//2])
```

```
AssertionError: Ensure x foofoo is equal to y foo.
```

Comment: Yeah, this is also a very reasonable solution! Thanks